# How to import from a *.properties and build.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, import

I have a project and it only contains *.jars and prop.properties and build.xml file.

I have tried the import way in eclipse but it did not work?

How can I import such a project into eclipse?

I appreaciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well normally build.xml file is contained in ant build projects. eclipse has the ability to run an ant project. try right clicking on build.xml and run as ant.

Comment: ok i tried, but just get an empty folder... is there possibly a better solution?